# Listeners for JButtton defined in another class and used in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I am working on from. Here in this frame on Button click of 'add Record' I add a panel to Jframe which is defined by extending JPanel class. Now I want that on button click of 'save' created in Panel, I want to get Text from textFields defined in panel which is to be stored in variables. On button click of save nothing happens.
Help me. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.sql.Savepoint;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import addPanel.panelAddForm;


public class frontPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

//----------*******Variable Declarations*******-------------------  
    JPanel  panelheaderImage, panelSideBar, panelTittle, panelTittleBar;

            //panelFrontPage;           

    JLabel  labelheaderImage, labelDate, labelTime, labelTittle, labelBottomImage;

    JButton buttonAddRecord, buttonSearch, buttonadd;

    JTextField nameSearch;

    Calendar currentDate;

    String year, month, day;

//------------------------------------------------------------------


//--------******FRAME CONSTRUCTOR*********------------------------  
    frontPage( )
    {

        //------------frame initialization--------
        setBackground( Color.BLUE );
        setSize( 750, 850 );
        setVisible( true );
        setLayout( null );

//------------frame initialization ENDS------------------------     

//------------Panel Initialization Starts----------------------

        framBottomImage frameimg = new framBottomImage();       
        frameBottom framebottom = new frameBottom();
        //frameAddForm addform= new frameAddForm();


        add( frameimg.panelBottomImage );
        add( framebottom.panelBottomText );
        //add( addform.panelAddForm );

        panelheaderImage = new JPanel( );
        panelheaderImage.setBounds( 0, 0, 600, 80 );
        add( panelheaderImage );

        panelSideBar = new JPanel( );
        panelSideBar.setBounds( 520, 90, 200, 40);
        panelSideBar.setLayout(null);
        add( panelSideBar );

        panelTittle = new JPanel();
        panelTittle.setLayout(null);
        panelTittle.setBounds(0, 85, 550, 30);
        add ( panelTittle );

        panelTittleBar = new JPanel( );
        panelTittleBar.setBounds( 0, 150, 450, 40);
        panelTittleBar.setLayout(null);
        add( panelTittleBar );

        /*panelFrontPage = new JPanel();
        panelFrontPage.setLayout(null);
        panelFrontPage.setBounds(0, 200, 500, 650);
        panelFrontPage.setEnabled(true);
        panelFrontPage.setVisible(true);
        add(panelFrontPage);*/

//------------Panel Initialization Ends---------------------------- 

        labelheaderImage = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( "C:\\Users\\SUN\\Desktop\\img.jpg" ) );
        panelheaderImage.add( labelheaderImage );


        currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.YEAR );
        month = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.MONTH );
        day = "" + currentDate.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

        labelDate = new JLabel( "Date:" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year );
        labelDate.setBounds(0, 0, 90, 20);
        panelSideBar.add( labelDate );

        labelTime = new JLabel( "Time:" );
        labelTime.setBounds(0, 20, 50, 20);
        panelSideBar.add( labelTime );

        labelTittle = new JLabel( "Patient's Case Paper" );
        labelTittle.setBounds( 150, 0, 250, 25);
        panelTittle.add( labelTittle );

        buttonAddRecord = new JButton( "ADD RECORD" );
        buttonAddRecord.setBounds( 25, 0, 110, 25 );
        buttonAddRecord.addActionListener(this);
        panelTittleBar.add( buttonAddRecord );

        nameSearch = new JTextField( "" );
        nameSearch.setBounds( 170, 0, 110, 25 );
        panelTittleBar.add( nameSearch );

        buttonSearch = new JButton( "Search" );
        buttonSearch.setBounds( 320, 0, 100, 25 );
        panelTittleBar.add( buttonSearch );

        buttonadd = new JButton( "add" );
        buttonadd.setBounds( 170, 410, 80, 25 );
        buttonadd.addActionListener(this);
        panelTittleBar.add( buttonadd );

    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
    {
        panelAddForm addform = new panelAddForm();
        addform.save.addActionListener(this);   

        if( ae.getSource( ) == buttonAddRecord )
        {
            addform.revalidate();
            addform.repaint();
            add( addform );
            System.out.println("at add record button end");
        } 

        if( ae.getSource() == addform.save )
        {
            System.out.println("Save Clicked");
        }

    }

}
```

class panelAddForm.java:

```
 package addPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.*;

public class panelAddForm extends JPanel 
{

    JLabel  labelName, labelFirstName, labelLastName, labelMiddleName,
            labelGender, labelAge, labelCity, labelContact, labelFees,
            labelNote, registrationId;

    public JTextField   textFieldFirstName, textFieldMiddleName, textFieldLastName,
                textFieldAge, textFieldCity, textFieldContact, textFieldFees,
                textFieldId;

    JTextArea textAreaNote;

    JRadioButton male, female;
    ButtonGroup selection;
    public JButton save, cancel;

    public panelAddForm()
    {
       this.setLayout(null);
       setVisible(true);
       setBounds(0, 200, 500, 450);

        registrationId= new JLabel("Registration Id");
        registrationId.setBounds(20, 0, 120, 20);
        add(registrationId);

        textFieldId = new JTextField();
        textFieldId.setBounds(130, 0, 50, 20);
        add(textFieldId);


        labelName = new JLabel( "Name" );
        labelName.setBounds( 20, 30, 50, 20);
        add(labelName);   

        labelFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
        labelFirstName.setBounds(100, 50, 80, 10);
        add(labelFirstName);

        textFieldFirstName = new JTextField(  );
        textFieldFirstName.setBounds( 100, 30, 80, 20 );

        textFieldFirstName.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldFirstName.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ 0-9,&%$#@!()*^,\t\n\f\r]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please Enter Valid Name",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }

        }
    } );

    add( textFieldFirstName );

//----------------------------------------MNAME---------------------------------------------------

    labelMiddleName= new JLabel("Middle Name");
    labelMiddleName.setBounds( 190, 50, 80,  10);
    add(labelMiddleName);


    textFieldMiddleName = new JTextField(  );
    textFieldMiddleName.setBounds( 190, 30, 80, 20 );

    textFieldMiddleName.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldMiddleName.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ 0-9,&%$#@!()*^]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please Enter Valid Name",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }

        }
    } );

    add( textFieldMiddleName );

//-----------------------------------labelName-----------------------------------------------------------

    labelLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    labelLastName.setBounds(280, 50, 80, 10);
    add(labelLastName);

    textFieldLastName = new JTextField(  );
    textFieldLastName.setBounds( 280, 30, 80, 20 );

    textFieldLastName.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldLastName.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ 0-9,&%$#@!()*^]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Please Enter Valid Name",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }
        }
    } );

    add( textFieldLastName );

    labelGender = new JLabel( "Gender" );
    labelGender.setBounds( 20, 70, 70, 20 );
    add(labelGender);

    selection = new ButtonGroup();

    male = new JRadioButton( "Male" );
    male.setBounds( 90, 70, 70, 20 );
    selection.add( male );
    add( male );

    female = new JRadioButton( "Female" );
    female.setBounds( 170, 70, 70, 20 );
    selection.add( male );
    add( female );

//---------------------AGE---------------------------------------   
    labelAge = new JLabel( "Age" );
    labelAge.setBounds( 20, 110, 50, 20 );
    add( labelAge );

    textFieldAge = new JTextField(  );
    textFieldAge.setBounds( 100, 110, 80, 20 );

    textFieldAge.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldAge.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ A-Z,a-z,&%$#@!()*^]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Numbers only",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }

        }
    } );
    add( textFieldAge );

    //---------------------CITY---------------------------------------
    labelCity = new JLabel( "City" );
    labelCity.setBounds( 20, 160, 80, 20 );
    add( labelCity );

    textFieldCity = new JTextField(  );
    textFieldCity.setBounds( 120, 160, 80, 20 );
    add(textFieldCity);

    textFieldCity.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldCity.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ 0-9,&%$#@!()*^]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Characters only",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }

        }
    } );

    //-----------------CONTACT---------------------------------------
    labelContact = new JLabel( "Phone Number" );
    labelContact.setBounds( 20, 210, 100, 20 );
    add( labelContact );

    textFieldContact = new JTextField( 10 );
    textFieldContact.setBounds( 120, 210, 80, 20 );
    add( textFieldContact );

    textFieldContact.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldContact.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "^[ 1-9][ 0-9]{12}$" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "numbers only",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }
        }
    } );

    add( textFieldContact );

    //-----------------NOTE---------------------------------------

    labelNote = new JLabel( "Note" );
    labelNote.setBounds( 20, 260, 140, 30 );
    add( labelNote );


    textAreaNote = new JTextArea();
    textAreaNote.setBounds(100, 260, 200, 50);
    add(textAreaNote);

    //----------------FEES--------------------------------------
    labelFees = new JLabel( "Consultation Fees" );
    labelFees.setBounds( 20, 330, 120, 20 );
    add( labelFees );

    textFieldFees = new JTextField(  );
    textFieldFees.setBounds( 140, 330, 80, 20 );
    add( textFieldFees );

    textFieldFees.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(  ) {
        public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
            String input = textFieldFees.getText(  );
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[ A-Z,a-z,&%$#@!(    )*^]" );
            Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
            if ( m.find(  ) ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Numbers only",
                        "Sorry", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }

        }
    } );

// ----------------------------------------------------

    save = new JButton( "SAVE" );
    save.setBounds( 25, 380, 70, 20 );
    //save.addActionListener( this );
    add( save );

    cancel = new JButton( "CANCEL" );
    cancel.setBounds( 150, 380, 80, 20 );
    //cancel.addActionListener( this );
    add( cancel );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you add your form inside the function that reacts to events from it, there will never be anything that can produce these events. Try moving these two lines out of `actionPerformed` and into `frontPage` or another intializing function.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae )
{
    panelAddForm addform = new panelAddForm();
    addform.save.addActionListener(this);   
    ...
}
```